# How to change json data value from ng-repeat to other value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in categories">
```

Javascript:

```
 $scope.categories = [ 
    { 
        "name": "Sport",
        "id": "50d5ad",
        "state": 1
    } , 
    {
        "name": "General",
        "id": "678ffr",
        "state": 2 
    } 
];
```

Sorry for the bad title, actually what i want try to say is 
"if state = 1" then at HTML below will say OK,

```
<p>Ok</p>
```

otherwise "if state = 2"

```
<p>Not Ok</p>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

extend your HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="data in categories">
  <p>{{show_ok(data)}}</p>
```

and then extend your controller

```
$scope.show_ok = function(data) {
  if (data.state === 1) {
     return 'Ok';
  } else if (data.state === 2) {
     return 'Not Ok'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in categories">
  <p ng-show="data.state == 1">Ok</p>
  <p ng-show="data.state == 2">Not Ok</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

mate, use this:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in categories">
  <p ng-if="data.state == 1">Ok</p>
  <p ng-if="data.state == 2">Not Ok</p>
</div>
```